# Python Random no function refreshes without running

Tags: python-3.x, random

My function is as below. I am taking input of 2 nos, finding random nos between them and then multiplying them all.

```
start = int(input("Enter start value"))
end =   int(input("Enter end value"))

import random

numlist = random.sample(range(start,end),10)
print("list of random nos are" + str(numlist))
from functools import reduce

prod = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, numlist)
print("the product of random nos: {0} is {1}".format(numlist,prod))
```

The output is as below

```
Enter start value7
Enter end value89
list of random nos are: [58, 13, 47, 43, 44, 56, 86, 14, 25, 71]
the product of random nos: [51, 30, 7, 25, 49, 29, 35, 54, 27, 67] is 1300840136977500
```

My question is a) why does the list of random nos change (first line `[58,13`..second line `[51,30`...) even though i haven't run this `numlist = random.sample(range(start,end),10)` line of code again.

What is happening here ?

Comment: cannot reproduce. What line are you printing `list of random nos are:` on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added  `print(numlist)` and the random numbers are not changing for me.Try this instead

```
end =   int(input("Enter end value"))

import random

numlist = random.sample(range(start,end),10)
print(numlist)
from functools import reduce

prod = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, numlist)
print("the product of random nos: {0} is {1}".format(numlist,prod))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a function so that the random value is regenerated each time the function is called.

````
>>> f = random.random()
>>> f
0.27924394986694034
>>> def randomizer():   return random.random()
...
>>> randomizer()
0.10425940372082476
>>> randomizer()
0.5703202999521394```
````

Comment: This isn't remotely related to what the OP is asking about.